# Dynamic options for Paperclip based on the content type

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2, paperclip

I am planning to use single table inheritance using the Paperclip gem that would be dynamic based on the content type.

```
class Document < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_attached_file :file, photo_options #if content type is an image
    has_attached_file :file, pdf_options #if content type is a pdf file
end

class Photo < Document
    # photo specific code
end

class Pdf < Document
    # pdf specific code
end
```

Is it possible to have the `has_attached_file` be dynamic based on the content type? One use case would be for when trying to create a new instance of `Document` from a file form upload:

```
@document = Document.new params[:document]
```

I hope my question makes sense. Thanks.

Comment: If you are using an STI model, why would you instance the superclass with a subclass behavior? Cant you think about it as a File as superclass and Document, Photo and Pdf as subclasses?

Comment: I'm using `= simple_form_for Document.new` in creating the form. I am trying to think of File (I'm just calling it Document) as a superclass with Photo and Pdf as subclasses. Are you suggesting that based on the params[:document], I should be instantiating the corresponding subclass instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like:

```
class Document < ActiveRecord::Base
end

class Photo < Document
  has_attached_file :file, photo_options #if content type is an image
  # photo specific code
end

class Pdf < Document
  has_attached_file :file, pdf_options #if content type is a pdf file
  # pdf specific code
end

class DocumentsController < ApplicationController
  #Assuming is the new method.
  def new
     @document = params[:document_type].classify.safe_constantize.new
  end
end
```

And use @document in your form.

Comment: Thanks. Works beautifully! :)